# How do I move canvas grid back to the accurate location of my previous frame

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm a 2D storyboard artist and this is my first time using Grease Pencil to draw the storyboard.

Here is the question:

How do I move my canvas grid back to the exact location of the previous frame?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the top center of the 3D window there are 3 dropdown menus:

The first defines the strokes placement, the second defines the drawing plane.

The grid is a visual reference of the drawing plane.

If you set the first as "origin" and the second as "XZ" you will establish a stable drawing plane and placement.

If you get familiar with thoose options you will be able to place the grid with any loc and orientation you need.